# Google maps how to get this working on device & geolocation html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

My code sets the zoom level for my desktop browser, but my device is SUPER zoomed in (like zoom level 20). How can I get the zoom to apply to both?

```
function CreateMap() {
        Data.$paymentMap.gmap({'center': GetLatLng(), 'zoom' : 15}).bind('init', function(evt, map) {
            Data.$paymentMap.gmap('watchPosition', function(position, status) {
                if (status === 'OK') {
                    Data.$paymentMap.gmap({'zoom' : 15});
                    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
                    var userMarker = Data.$paymentMap.gmap('get', 'markers > user' );

                    if (!userMarker) {
                        Data.$paymentMap.gmap('addMarker', { 'id': 'user', 'position': GetLatLng(), 'bounds': true, icon: '/images/trunk/icon/icon-map-marker.png' });
                    } else {
                        userMarker.setPosition(latlng);
                        map.panTo(latlng);
                    }
                } 
            });
        });
    }
```